# Does implicit operator have higher priority over ToString() method?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, overloading, operator-keyword

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static implicit operator int(Test t) { return 42; }
    public override string ToString() { return "Test here!"; }
}

var test = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(test); // 42
Console.WriteLine((Test)test); // 42
Console.WriteLine((int)test); // 42
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString()); // "Test here!"
```

Why in the first three cases we have answer `42` even if we explicitly cast to `Test`?
Does `implicit` operator have higher priority over `ToString()` ?

Comment: In fact, it does. You could try to find the reason in the following topic of the [Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=188622): *6.4.4 User-defined implicit conversions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Implicit operators have precedence over explicit operators. The language specification states that implicit operators should not loose information, while this is allowed for explicit operators. See for instance, [MSDN explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx). If you change the keyword `implicit` to `explicit` you will see `Test here!` 3 times, and 42 once.

```
public class Test
{
    public static explicit operator int(Test t) { return 42; }
    public override string ToString() { return "Test here!"; }
}

var test = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(test); // "Test here!"
Console.WriteLine((Test)test); // "Test here!"
Console.WriteLine((int)test); // 42
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString()); // "Test here!"
```