# Order of implicit conversions in c#

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

What is the order of implicit conversions done in Console.WriteLine(x) when x is an object from user-defined class:

```
    class Vector
    {
        public int x = 12;       

        public static implicit operator double(Vector v1)
        {
            return 3.14;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(Vector v1)
        {
            return 42;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.x.ToString();
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector v11 = new Vector();
        Console.WriteLine(v11);
    }
```

Why I get 42, and not 3.14 or "12"? Why I can not add an additional implicit conversion to string /there is Compiler error on the ambiguity between  CW(int) and CW(string)/:

```
        public static implicit operator string(Vector v1)
        {
            return "42";
        }
```

I know I should avoid using the implicit cast, but just for curiosity!

Comment: No, it prints 42 (fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition)

Comment: I'm going to assume that it returns `42` because `v11.x` is an `int`, not a `double` or `string` and that when `v11` is used in `Console.WriteLine()`, it calls `Vector`'s `ToString()` method, which calls `v11.x.ToString()`.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I guess it´s because the operator returning a string is the best match. All the others require further boxing. However that doesn´t expalin why `ToString` isn´t used...

Comment: C# overload resolution is the most fun bit in the spec! And by "fun" I mean "hideously complicated when you get down to it and hopefully doing what you want so you don't have to dig into the details". The `Console.WriteLine` overload taking `int` is considered "better", for a [very specific interpretation of "better"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-function-member). I haven't worked through it to get to the exact details. If Eric Lippert has time he'll pop up and explain it. :-)

Comment: This piqued my curiosity, so I went and found [Does implicit operator have higher priority over ToString() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202473/does-implicit-operator-have-higher-priority-over-tostring-method) - and answer is yes, it does.

Comment: I believe that the link @stuartd provided has the correct answer.  However, I am not sure whether we should declare this question as a duplicate...

Comment: In fact, the linked question is *not* a duplicate, since no explicit call to `ToString` is involved here. The question of why `Console.WriteLine(int)` is chosen as the method to call, and not (say) `Console.WriteLine(double)`, is not answered by the other question, nor is why adding another conversion produces an ambiguity. Many and interesting are the issues caused by overload resolution and conversions, but they're not all equivalent.

Comment: Not so sure the C# language specification allows this, ought to be ambiguous by the stated rules in chapter 6.4.4.  But these are primitive types, it always favor the cheap conversion over the expensive one.  *int* is the cheapest there is.  Only decimal vs double is reported as ambiguous.

Comment: No, I don't think it's ambiguous. Given two overloads, one taking an `int` and one a `double`, and a type implicitly convertible to both, the overload taking an `int` is taken because `int` is a [better conversion target](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-conversion-target). This is because `int` implicitly converts to `double`, but not the other way around. When an implicit conversion to `string` is added, the result is ambiguous because there are no implicit conversions between `int` and `string`, and neither is better.

Comment: The presence or absence of `.ToString` is a red herring in this case because it's never involved: that would require that the `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload be picked so `.ToString()` can be invoked in the background. That's only possible with an explicit cast, since `object` is never the better target if there's a choice.

Comment: Reopened as the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202473/does-implicit-operator-have-higher-priority-over-tostring-method) gives background information, but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Note that the once duplicate of this question is in fact asking exactly the same thing as this question, it's just that the answer is completely wrong (even though it has a positive score and is accepted).  Since there was no correct answer, it indeed should not have been a duplicate target.  (An explanation of how explicit operators behave doesn't explain why implicit operators produce the results they do in the example shown in both questions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what is printed is based entirely on what overload of `Console.WriteLine` is chosen.  Which overload is chosen is based on section 7.5.3.2 of the specs on "betterness" for function members.

An overload is "better" than another, when it has a parameter that is "more specific" than another one.  "more specific" means there's an implicit conversion from the more specific type to the less specific type, and *no* implicit conversion from the less specific type to the more specific type.

`object` is the least specific overload, as there's no implicit conversion from it to int, double, or string, but there is one from every type to it.  int is more specific than double because there's an implicit conversion from int to double, but no conversion from double to int.  int and string have no implicit conversions between each other, so neither is more specific, and so neither is better or worse than the other.

So if there's an implicit conversion from your object to `string` then the string overload is considered, and there's a tie for "best" overload, and you get an error.  When it's missing there's a "most specific" type of all of the considered overloads (which is `int`), so it's "the best", and that overload is chosen.